# Suppose that X and Y are independent geometric random variable, where X has parameter p and Y has parameter q.

Tags: statistics, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I would like to calculate the conditional expectation $E(X|X>Y)$.
I reckon that there are two scenarios for solving this question. But the ansewers are not the same in the end and I am confused by this.

**First scenario**

Firstly, we compute $E(X|X>y)$:

$E(X|X>y) = \sum x\frac{P(X \ = \  x, \ X \ > \ y)}{P(X \ > \ y)} \\ =\sum_{x\ = \ y +1} \ x\frac{(1 \ - \ p)^x \ p}{(1 \ - \ p)^y} \\ = y \ + \ \frac{1}{p}$

As $E(X|X>Y) \ = \ E(E(X|X>Y,Y)) \ = \ E(E(X|X>y))$, therefore,

$E(X|X>Y) = E(y \ + \ \frac{1}{p}) \ = \ \frac{1}{q} \ + \ \frac{1}{p}$

**Second scenario**(I think this is correct!)

$E(X|X>Y) = \sum x\frac{P(X \ = \  x, \ X \ > \ Y)}{P(X \ > \ Y)} \\ 
=\frac{1}{P(X \ > \ Y)}\sum_{x}x \ P(X \ = \ x)P(Y \ < \ x)$

Comment: Is it true that $E(X \mid X > Y) = E(E(X \mid X > Y, Y))$? I don't see why on top of my head.

Comment: In general for event $A$ and rv $X$: $$\mathbb E[X|A]=\frac{\mathbb EX1_A}{P(A)}$$

Comment: @WillM. Mixing event and sigma algebra conditioning is always fraught with peril. (so use drhab's identity to avoid it)  But mainly it was the next step that held the error $\mathsf E(X\mid X>Y, Y=y)\neq \mathsf E(X\mid X>y)$

Comment: @drhab I know that but I don't see how that helps, what is $E(X \mid E, Y)$ where $E$ is an event and $Y$ a $\sigma$-field?

Comment: $$\mathsf E(X\mid A)=\dfrac{\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mathbf 1_{A}\mid \sigma(Y)))}{\mathsf P(A)}$$

Comment: Your second is $\dfrac{\sum_{x}x \ P(X \ = \ x)P(Y \ < \ x)}{\sum_{x} \ P(X \ = \ x)P(Y \ < \ x)}$ and in general correct for any independent discrete random variables

Comment: I removed the [tag:geometric-probability] tag; it's for questions about geometry and probability, not about the geometric distribution. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is based on an erroneous claim that $X$ is conditionally independent of $Y$ when given $X>Y$. Surely it cannot be so. $$\mathsf P(X=x\mid X>Y, Y=y)~\neq~\mathsf P(X=x\mid X>y)$$

---

Rather, indeed you should indeed use the second approach. $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X\mid X>Y)&=\sum_{x=2}^\infty x\,\mathsf P(X=x\mid X>Y)\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\sum_{x=2}^\infty x\,\mathsf P(X=x)\,\mathsf P(Y<x)}{\mathsf P(X>Y)}\\&=\dfrac{pq\sum_{x=2}^\infty x(1-p)^{x-1}\sum_{y=1}^{x-1}(1-q)^{y-1}}{pq\sum_{x=2}^\infty (1-p)^{x-1}\sum_{y=1}^{x-1}(1-q)^{y-1}}\end{align}$$

Comment: sorry but why your sum goes from $x=2$?

Comment: $\mathsf E(X)=1/p$ and $\mathsf E(Y)=1/q$ indicates we're using the 1-shifted geometric random variables (ie with the support of $\{1,2,\ldots\}$).  So the condition $X>Y$ requires we must sum over $1\leq y < x$ ; which is to say: $2\leq x$ and $1\leq y\leq x-1$

Comment: Much Thanks! Do you mean that $P(X = x, X > Y | Y = y) ≠ P(X = x, X > y)$  as X and Y are not independent in this case?

Comment: To be clear: The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not conditionally independent under the event $X>Y$.